# Is there a way to express $\frac{a}{x+y}$ in a more usable and simplifiable form?

Tags: number-theory

I have made a previous post: [Why does $\frac{x}{ln(x+1)}$ = Something that includes factorials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200126/why-does-x-lnx1-something-that-includes-factorials)

In here, the answerer whose answer I accepted had stated that something in the form $\frac{a}{x+y}$ doesn't necessarily $ = \frac{a}{x}+\frac{a}{y}$

Example:$ \frac{2}{1+1} $ doesn't equal $2(\frac{2}{1})$s , since 1 doesn't equal 4.

Therefore, I cannot split the terms up individually.

Is there a way I can put this in the form of [term]+[term]+[term]+[term]+[term]+...

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you referred to an infinite series, you could say
\begin{align*}
    \frac{a}{x+y} &= \frac{a}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{y}{x}}
    = \frac{a}{x} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{y}{x}\right)^n
    \\&= \frac{a}{x}\left(1 - \frac{y}{x} + \frac{y^2}{x^2} - \frac{y^3}{x^3} + \dots\right)
    \\&= \frac{a}{x} - \frac{ay}{x^2} + \frac{ay^2}{x^3} - \frac{ay^3}{x^4} + \dots
\end{align*}
The series converges as long as $|y| < |x|$.  If $|y|>|x|$, reverse the roles of $x$ and $y$. If $y=x$, then $\frac{a}{x+y} = 2\frac{a}{x}$.

However, I guess this doesn't fit your description of “a more useable and simplifiable form.”  The shorter, more direct answer is that you can't distribute a sum over a quotient like you can over a product.